# How to configure the data servers for a pnfs metadata server?

Tags: 18.04, nfs, storage

I am trying to deploy a PNFS setup. Have set up an MDS that the client is talking to. /proc/self/mountstats shows the mount is pnfs enabled. I cannot find any documentation on how to configure the list of data servers (DS) on the MDS. I want to run DS on a different machine from MDS. How can I supply the DS ip address and storage path to the MDS?
I have seen the following links but this information is not available there:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch09s02
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-pnfs

Obsolete setup steps - https://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php?title=PNFS_Setup_Instructions&oldid=5568

I have the following setup so far -
A Ubuntu 18.04 that I am using as the Metadata server (MDS).

```
root@ubuntu1804:/etc# uname -a
Linux ubuntu1804 4.15.0-45-generic
```

I have configured it use pnfs by exporting a root filesystem with "pnfs".

```
root@ubuntu1804:/etc# cat /etc/exports
/srv            *(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,pnfs)
```

A centos 7.5 system that supports FlexFile layouts as the NFS v4.1 client. I mount the exported filesystem as -

```
# mount -t nfs -o v4.1 -o rw <nfs-server-ip>:/ /mnt/
```

mountstats shows that pnfs is enabled

```
#  cat /proc/self/mountstats
device nfsd mounted on /proc/fs/nfsd with fstype nfsd device <server-ip>:/ mounted on /mnt with fstype nfs4
statvers=1.1
opts:   rw,vers=4.1,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.122.5,local_lock=none
age:    45
impl_id:        name='',domain='',date='0,0'
caps:   caps=0x3ffdf,wtmult=512,dtsize=32768,bsize=0,namlen=255
nfsv4:  bm0=0xfdffbfff,bm1=0x40f9be3e,bm2=0x803,acl=0x3,sessions,pnfs=LAYOUT_FLEX_FILES
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked on the linux-nfs mailing list and they confirmed that this is not possible to do this with flexfile layouts. The upstream linux knfsd server currently only supports a very simple flexfiles layout where the MDS and the DS are the same server, so there's no way (as of 4.20 kernel version) to configure knfsd to give out flexfiles layouts that point to other DS servers.