# How to install and configure pNFS on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nfs

Does Ubuntu20.04 support pNFS Server(Data and MetaData) and Client side of pNFS?

If YES, Then How to install and configure it? Is there any comprehensive guide?

How to install and configure pNFS Servers, MetaData Servers, and clients on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

I've stopped searching about this topic and I will continue in the future but these are what I'd found.

They've added this man page to newer Ubuntu distros: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man4/pnfs.4freebsd.html

And in [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445161&p=13964263#post13964263) an active member said:

> From what I have read, kernel 4.12+ has supported pNFS which means
> Ubuntu 18.04 and higher. NFS protocol 4.1 was the version that had
> built-in support for pNFS.
>
> I have not done this before but from what I am seeing, there is not a
> flexible way of setting this up regarding redundancy and scalability.
>
> [How to configure the data servers for a pnfs metadata server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121663/how-to-configure-the-data-servers-for-a-pnfs-metadata-server)
>
> I also have not to see ANYTHING "comprehensive" regarding this
> subject. There are some bits and pieces about setting it up but
> nowhere have I found someone steps thru the entire process and then
> proceeds to show any test results showing how it is any better than a
> standard NFS design...which has many comprehensive setup guides.

I will do some practice and share them here if I get positive results in the future.